# Memory get increase but not release on dismiss [Mapbox]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am using MapBox for navigation in my app. After selecting source and destination, I redirect it to Mapbox SDK by presenting the screen. At this moment my memory get increase 180mb, after get dismiss from controller ,my memory doesn't release and it get increase continuously. I have done the following on my viewDidDisappear.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = false
    mapview = nil
    suspendNotifications()
    routeController.suspendLocationUpdates()
    
}
```

After multiple present and dismiss with different location, memory get increase to 680MB and after certain period app get crash.

I have attached the instruments screens , where it shows the mapbox functions which get increase after dismiss controller.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there any retain cycle involved in it?

Comment: no.. not identify such retain cycle. I only present and dismiss controller .

Comment: Can you show that presentation and dismissal code? Also check if there are any flaws in your navigation.

Comment: Check if `deinit` is getting called or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add cleanup code into the `deinit` method

```
  deinit {
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = false
    mapview = nil
    suspendNotifications()
    routeController.suspendLocationUpdates()
 }
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, check for memory leaks in your code using instrument.